# Why do I see an "Hiding Questions" message for non-existent tags?

Tags: bug, tags

When trying to view the [Status-By-Design](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/status-bydesign) tag on Gaming.SE I see this message:

[image]

This tag apparently doesn't exist, nor have I ignored it.

When I try to view the tag page for a tag I have ignored, I don't see this message:

[image]

Why is this message appearing?

Comment: I noticed other bug: I don't see my ignored tags anymore unless I click "edit" on the favorite tags.

Comment: By the way, this tag exist on the meta site: http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/status-bydesign

Comment: @shadowwizard Yes I realize it does but this behavior is only on the main site. I still thought it was worth bringing up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why is this message appearing?

Because you have ignored tags, and you have set ignored tags to be hidden in your preferences. Because of that, that message will show up for *any list of questions at all*, whether or not any results are *actually* hidden because of your ignored tags - just to remind you that some questions are hidden.

> When I try to view the tag page for a tag I have ignored, I don't see this message:

The message will be at the bottom - your screenshot is just of the top. If I visit the [Bridge tag on Board Games](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bridge), I'll still see the message saying I have the Bridge tag hidden.

[image: screenshot of the message at the bottom of the list]

Comment: Ah yes so it is. I do feel a little silly for not noticing that before. Thanks for clearing it up.