# Message that questions are being hidden when none actually are

Tags: bug, tags, ignored-tags

On [Science Fiction & Fantasy](https://scifi.stackexchange.com), I have a few tags ignored ([a-song-of-ice-and-fire], [dune], and [fan-fiction]). I've set them to be completely hidden, not just grayed out. This works completely as it should.

However, I get [a message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eYfHG.png) when looking at questions on tags with no questions in common with these that questions are being hidden, such as [led-zeppelin] and [moon]. This also happens when I search with queries about tags, such as `[poe-dameron] -[star-wars]`, that don't apply to any questions with my hidden tags. These make no sense at all, and I believe they shouldn't be there.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Don't tell me you're "hiding questions" when there are none to begin with](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/226617/dont-tell-me-youre-hiding-questions-when-there-are-none-to-begin-with). While the *behavior* has changed, so that the examples there don't match the question, the question is the duplicate of this; and quite old.